# PHP: Find string in file and print the next few characters

Tags: php

```
[amount] = "58"
```

I have a large text file, and am trying to find where amount occurs and print the 58, as I am scraping HTML on multiple pages, all with similar layouts, but the amount value changes on each page. The only constant is that the string [amount] occurs once, so I am able to use it to find the number value.
I would like to know how to do this in PHP.

Thanks.

The code I tried with was

```
$filename = 'site.txt';

$searchfor = '[amount]';

$file = file_get_contents($filename);

if(strpos($file, $searchfor [$offset = 6]))
{
    echo $searchfor;
}
```

Comment: Tip: use `strpos()` in combination with `substr()` OR use `preg_match()`. Read more: http://php.net/ And better post some code from your tryout ;-)

Comment: But not as comment, update your question. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to find the number 58, this can be done e.g.

input was `site.txt`:

```
some text [amount] = "58" some other text
```

running on cli: `php test.php`:

```
<?php

$filename = './site.txt';
$searchfor = '[amount]';
$file = file_get_contents($filename);

foreach( explode("\n", $file) as $line ){
    $found = strpos($line, $searchfor);
    if($found){
        echo "string found on position: ".$found." in '" . $line. "'\n";
        echo "so the searched stuff should be: '" . explode('"', substr($line,$found,strlen($line)-$found))[1] ."'\n";
    }
}

?>
```

results in output:

```
string found on position: 10 in 'some text [amount] = "58" some other text'
so the searched stuff should be: '58'
```

Comment: Unfortunately your code just prints the entire file, despite finding the string. Thanks for trying though :)

Comment: well, here I have the above mentioned two files and it produces the output I quoted as well. probably you run it differently. and as you did not give information on your input data (e.g. quote the file) … well, I cannot do much about.

Comment: Your solution worked in the end, I was just being dumb about something. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

```
$filename = 'site.txt'; 
$searchfor = '[amount] = "'; 
$file = file_get_contents($filename); 
//find the position
$pos = strpos($file, $searchfor);
//check for real false here
if($pos!==false) { 
   //print from the found postion+lengthofserachfor
   //(int) makes an real number if you get '6 abc' an real 6
   echo (int)substr($file,$pos+strlen($searchfor),5); 
}
```

So far, done.

```
if(preg_match('#amount\][ ]?=[ ]?"([0-9]+)#',$file,$matches)){
    print_r($matches);
}
```

Have a nice day.